# Microsoft Graph Drive search

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm attempting to modify the node.js Quick Start example to produce a list of the user's excel documents, but I'm running into issues.

This query works (returns a non-empty result) in the Graph Explorer:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='.xlsx')?select=name,id,webUrl
```

I have tried a few ways to reproduce it in graphHelpers.js.
This query returns an empty result:

```
function getExcelDocs(accessToken, callback) {
  // Get list of excel docs in the user's onedrive
  request
   .get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='.xlsx')?select=name,id,webUrl")
   .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken)
   .end((err, res) => {
     // Returns 200 OK and the search result in the body. 
     callback(err, res);
   });
}
```

If I substitute the search URL with the drive children query, I get back a non-empty set of documents.

```
.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children')
```

Is there a problem with how I'm formatting the query url?

Comment: Have you tried encoding the URL (i.e. encodeURIComponent() )?

Comment: What part of the URL would you suggest encoding?  Clearly the get request will fail if I encode the colon and slashes.  I will try encoding the brackets and single-quotes.

Comment: Just the query portion: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q%3D'.xlsx')%3Fselect%3Dname%2Cid%2CwebUrl

Comment: Unfortunately this returned a bad request result.

Comment: I'm not familure with this `graphHelpers.js` library but it sounds like it may be unable to handle the search query correctly. Do you have a link to the graphHelpers.js project? Its hard to tell without looking at the code itself.

Comment: Hi Marc, Thanks for following up. I'm using the node.js quickstart, modified graphHelpers.js with the above function.  The Microsoft repo is here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-connect-rest-sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parens in the URI are causing the problem here. The content within those parens represents the `body` of the request. The underlying library that is processing this request ([SuperAgent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/)) doesn't seem to like them going directly into the URI.

I believe you can fix this by providing the URL components separately:

```
request
  .get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search", "q='.xlsx'")
  .query({ select: 'name,id,webUrl'})
  .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken)
  .end((err, res) => {
      // Returns 200 OK and the search result in the body. 
      callback(err, res);
  });
```

Alternatively, this might also work:

```
request
  .get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search")
  .query({ select: 'name,id,webUrl'})
  .send("q='.xlsx'")
  .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken)
  .end((err, res) => {
      // Returns 200 OK and the search result in the body. 
      callback(err, res);
  });
```